# Set 404 http status code for wordpress site in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have a URLs for which I want to set 404 http status code in htaccess in a wordpress site.

https://www.infocera.com/oppo-find.html

I am trying the code

```
RewriteRule /oppo-find - [L,R=404]
```

However the below mentioned URLs shall open normally.

https://www.infocera.com/oppo-find.html

I am not able to get desired result. Can anyone give me inputs on the same. The https://www.infocera.com/oppo-find gets 301 redirect to https://www.infocera.com/oppo-find.html which than shows 404 status with my current code.

Best rgds

Jai

.......................

```
 RewriteEngine On
# ensure www and https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.infocera.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.infocera.com/$1 [L,R=301]
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# 404 status code for category slugs
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/oppo-find/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/garmin-forerunner/?$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=[01]$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [L,NC,R=404]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.infocera.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(images/[^.]+)\.jpg$ /$1.webp [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: You've likely put the code in the wrong place. Please include your complete `.htaccess` file with this directive in place. However, from the network traffic, the 301 redirect is triggered by Cloudflare (cache) / Permalink Manager (Wordpress). If you've put the directive in the right place then WordPress would not be instantiated. (So, any directive you put in `.htaccess` is not going to do anything until Cloudflare is updated.)

Comment: Plz find my htaccess full code above and share the code you feel shall work. I will use tht and clear Clodflare cache before testing. thnx

Comment: Have edited question and added full htaccess file content. thnx

Comment: In custom permalink plugin, there is this note "Automatic redirect for native URI enabled: oppo-find" I am trying to see how this can be disabled. thnx

Comment: With your updated code block... where did you place the directive in question and where are the other "WordPress" directives? (Yes, that "permalink plugin" would seem to be causing the redirect, however, as I mentioned above, if the rule in question had been placed in the correct place in relation to the WordPress directives then WordPress should not even be instantiated.)

Comment: I placed the 404 directive in question in the end of htaccess full code I pasted above and than tested. Below that lies super cache codes which have no impact on this.

Comment: But where is the "WordPress code block"? This is the front-controller pattern that routes all requests through WordPress - without which your site will not function as stated?! I've also just noticed the `#RewriteEngine On` directive is commented out!? Without this, the mod_rewrite directives aren't doing anything (unless perhaps it is enabled in a parent config). There seems to be "something else" going on here with how your server is configured?

Comment: Hi MrWhite plz check the update code in question now. It is not working. May be wordpress has default function (most likely) which 301 redirects a slug to its respective URL. I could not find a way around where separate status code can be shown for a slug and its main URL. In this ex. URL in question "oppo-find" is a slug and "oppo-find.html" is corresponding URL. plz share your views. thnx